# What is the purpose of the name for Swagger's body parameter?

Tags: rest, http, swagger

As shown below, I name the body parameter `main_name_of_parameter`:

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: Learing Swagger Title
  description: Learing Swagger Description
schemes:
  - http
host: testing.example.com
basePath: /api
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

paths:
 /test:
    post:
      summary: testing a post
      description: testing a post
      parameters:
        - name: main_name_of_parameter
          in: body
          description: main_name_of_parameter
          schema:
            properties:
              property_one:
                type: string
              property_two:
                type: string
```

Then I test it using the swagger UI, and it generates the following curl:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "property_one": "string", \ 
   "property_two": "string" \ 
 }' 'http://testing.example.com/api/test'
```

As seen, `main_name_of_parameter` was never sent to the server.  What is the purpose of the name for Swagger's body parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the name is used for code generators, as the parameter name for the methods that are generated.  But as you stated, there isn't really a use for the name, and in fact it is being [removed in the 3.0 specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/670).

Comment: I am very new to Swagger, and I thought it was just my misunderstanding and there was some secrete purpose.  Glad it isn't!